# sql join 1 to many - avoid repeating columns for parent

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a scenario where there is a contact table (id,name) and phone numbers table (id,phone,contactid). 1 contact can have many phone numbers. I would like to show the output as follows:

```
|Contact   | Phone   |
|----------|---------|  
|contact 1 | phone 1 | 
|          | phone 2 | 
|          | phone 3 | 
|contact 2 | phone 4 | 
|contact 3 | phone 5 | 
|          | phone 6 | 
|          | phone 7 |
```

Basically I do not want to repeat contact column when there are multiple matching phone numbers. is this possible?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?  mySQL or PostgreSQL?  It can't be both; unless you're saying the solution needs to work on both platforms.

Comment: Could you explain why you dont want repeated contacts? I guess it is possible in MySQL, but will require some subqueries which will decrease the performance of the query. As for postgresql I am not sure

Comment: @piotrgajow want to export the results to csv, and the user doesn't want to see repeated rows.

Comment: If you used another programming language like PHP to generate your CSV file, it is possible, but I don't think it is possible to have an empty string for repeated value directly in the output of your SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using window functions and a inline view; we can accomplish this.

We generate a set of data where each name has a row_number assigned to it for each different name, starting over at 1 again for each new name encountered.  For example:

```
|Contact   | Phone   | RN
|----------|---------|  
|contact 1 | phone 1 | 1
|          | phone 2 | 2
|          | phone 3 | 3
|contact 2 | phone 4 | 1
|contact 3 | phone 5 | 1
|          | phone 6 | 2
|          | phone 7 | 3

SELECT Case when RN= 1 then C.Name end as Contact, Phone
FROM
    (SELECT C.Name, P.Phone, row_number() over (partition by C.Contact order by P.Phone) RN
     FROM  contact C
     INNER JOIN phoneNumbers P
    ) As InLineVIew
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best idea but it's quite easy to do:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN contact ELSE NULL END AS contact
  ,phone 
FROM
(
  SELECT 
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY contact)
     ,contact 
     ,phone 
  FROM foo
) q
ORDER BY contact, row_number, phone;
```