# MS Access: Can a grouping be displayed on the left side of the detail section instead of above it?

Tags: group-by, ms-access-2010, design-view

Imagine a regular ol' report that has generated data and has one grouping level. We all know that grouping adds a section above the detail section and in here we can put in the controls that hold the grouped fields.

*However*, is there a way to display the grouped fields on the left of the detail section instead of above it? I know it's incredibly counter-intuitive because when you open up Access in design view, you don't have a place to put fields to the left of the Detail section - you can either put it inside or outside. But is this somehow possible?

I thought of using a subreport, but then the next question would be - how can I make the subreport generate data that lines up nicely with the data in the Detail section of the main report?

Is this possible?

**Update:**

Image of what Access currently does.

http://imgur.com/tbr8jz4

Image of what I'd like it to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Re2E.jpg

Basically, I just want to show the stuff from the grouped section to the left of the detail section. It would not be repeated for each record.

Comment: So... why not stick with the one grouping level and simply add the grouped fields or are you still not wanting the grouping to be repeated on every row?  Picture probably worth 1000 words here.

Comment: I hear ya @xQbert . It does kind of seem unnecessary to try this but I was just curious if it can be done. I'll try to come up with a picture. To answer your question - correct, I do not want the grouping to be repeated on every row. I only want to show the grouped fields **ONCE** next to each set of rows.

Comment: @xQbert images added.

Comment: Outside of access we could use a window function to assign a row numbers starting at one for each group and then use a case statement to eliminate displaying values for the group name row number is > 1.  So combining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917637/achieving-row-number-partition-by-in-ms-access with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221224/sql-join-1-to-many-avoid-repeating-columns-for-parent?noredirect=1#comment60074794_36221224 may do the trick  So YES I believe it's possible.  though we may not be able to "Center" it easily.

Comment: @xQbert what do you mean by "outside of access"?

Comment: I mean in a RDBMS such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, there's soemthing called window functions.  The 1st link shows how to emulate those that in Access